# Организации "архитектуры" приложения WPF

Tags: c#

Имеется приложение WPF которое выполняет нехитрые манипуляции, далее возникла необходимость например работы с данными из сторонних источников по средством API.
Вопрос как правильно внедрять этот функционал ?
Правильно ли будет в VS добавить в решение  проект ASP.NET -> Web API (или любой  другой  проект по необходимости) ?

Спасибо

Comment: а как организованно ваше приложение? Если вы организовываете все правильно, то у вас должна добавляться бизнес логика, которая вам нужна путем расширения (не редактирования) кода.

Comment: Я бы написал класс-обертку для взаимодействия с этим API, потом можно будет его использовать в других проектах, или изменить в одном месте, если внесут изменения в API.

Comment: да как раз происходит расширение кода,  вопрос как  это расширение правильно  производить : добавлением  шаблона  нового проекта или пытаться   реализовывать это "шаблон" самому ?